# DNS nameserver change - testing - AWS Route 53

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I'm about to launch to production a new version of our site.

Needless to say, switching from a hosted server and wordpress to a complex webapp that runs on AWS ECS and that sits behing an ELB.

Just when I wanted to pull the switch, I found out that the only way to make an A registry to our ELB is to have DNS records hosted with Route53.

As you know, A records do not allow URL's like the ELB one, and you can't setup TOP LEVEL CNAME's.

I moved all record sets to a Route53 hosted zone, it all looks good.

The question is, can I maybe configure my PC locally to use the new AWS Nameservers to do some testing before I change it definetivly?

I have googled but haven't found anything, and I'm pretty sure it's not posible, but hopefully I'm wrong.

Let me know if I didn't explain myself well enought

Comment: What is your PC OS?

Comment: Linux, but I can use Windows too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your workstation runs Linux, you can try [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).

CentOS instructions (should be very similar for other distros)

```
yum install epel-release
yum install dnsmasq
```

Modify your network configuration so that 127.0.0.1 is used as your first name server and your usual DNS server as secondary:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Find out ip address of one of your AWS DNS servers for your domain:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# dig ns-1587.awsdns-06.co.uk +short
205.251.198.51
```

Configure dnsmasq to forward queries for your domain to AWS by adding the line to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

`server=/example.com/205.251.198.51`

Restart dnsmasq:
`service dnsmasq restart`